# Escape key stops working, I have to use Shift + ESC

Tags: windows

Yesterday I found that my escape key wasn't working in some programs, but Shift + ESC works fine. It's really annoying though if I'm gaming and I have to exit out of a menu quickly. I accidentally broke the drivers and restarted my pc a couple of times, and my second keyboard's escape key worked fine. when I got my normal keyboard fixed it worked for the rest of the night, but the next day the problem was back. What can I do? I'm desperate.

Computer: Alienware Aurora R12 Ryzen Edition

Windows Version: Windows 11 Pro 21H2

Comment: "escape key wasn't working in some programs" - did it work on other programs?

Comment: It works in chrome, but I tested it in Minecraft, Among Us and Blender and it doesn't work.

Comment: what you wrote makes no sense ... please describe clearly what you did that led to the problem ... `I accidentally broke the drivers and restarted my pc a couple of times, and my second keyboard's escape key worked fine. when I got my normal keyboard fixed it worked for the rest of the night, but the next day the problem was back`

Comment: I didn't do anything that led to the problem. one day it was working, the next day it wasn't.

Comment: I have the same issue. What's even weirder is that for me this happens both on Windows 10 and on Linux w/ KDE5.